# Check string includes integer at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to check whether the given string includes `"test_icon_<integer>"`. the integer could be 10 or 22 or 32 or 109 or 120.( first integer can't be zero but second and third digits can be zero)

```
Following strings are not accepted
1."test_icon_<1a>" 
2."test_icon_<1.1>"
3. "test_icon_<!@q>"
4. "test_icon_<abced>"
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Try matching with regular expresseions!

Comment: Question is unclear. 1. Is the issue whether the string **includes** `"test_icon_<integer>"` or **is** `"test_icon_<integer>"`? 2. Is the issue whether the string **includes** a `"test_icon_<integer>"` **without** any alphabets in `<>`, or the string does **not include** a `"test_icon_<integer>"` **with** alphabets in `<>`?

Comment: @sawa I have edited my question. Let me know if it is still unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex matches your strings and fails on the bad ones:

```
test_icon_<[1-9]\d{0,2}>
```

see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/bG6zP7).

**Explain Regex**

```
test_icon_<              # 'test_icon_<'
[1-9]                    # any character of: '1' to '9'
\d{0,2}                  # digits (0-9) (between 0 and 2 times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
>                        # '>'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
test_icon_<((?!0)\d)\d{0,2}>
```

[**Demo with explanation**](http://regex101.com/r/mJ6cE5)

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should solve your problem:

```
/test_icon_\<[0-9]+\>/
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The first digit cannot be a 0, yours still matches in that case (e.g., `test_icon_<01>`). Also, you do not have to escape `<` and `>`.